# Get on focus message with keyboard navigation on input field inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem when I try to focus with keyboard, I don't get the attribute message.

This works with mouse hover but I want to get the same result with keyboard arrow navigation. what I try to accomplish is to get the same result with keyboard focus.

css:

```
[data-tip] {
position:relative;}

[data-tip]:before {
content:'';
/* hides the tooltip when not hovered */
display:none;
content:'';
display:none;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid #1a1a1a;
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:35px;
z-index:8;
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
width:0;
height:0;
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:35px;
z-index:8;
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
width:0;
height:0;}

[data-tip]:after {
display:none;
content:attr(data-tip);
position:absolute;
top:35px;
left:0px;
padding:5px 8px;
background:#1a1a1a;
color:#fff;
z-index:9;
font-size: 0.75em;
height:18px;
line-height:18px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
white-space:nowrap;
word-wrap:normal;} 

[data-tip]:hover:before,
[data-tip]:hover:after {
display:block;}
```

cshtml:

```
case "something":
            return '<div data-tip="Message">\
                        <input id="i-something-{0}" type="text" maxlength="1" class="input full-width validate[custom[yesOrNo]] hover" placeholder="something" {1}/>\
                    </div>'.format(rowId, v);
```

Comment: Please post code not picture of code